# Yahoo Developer error "An internal error occurred (eid 7320968)"

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I'm trying to pass through "Yahoo OAuth 2.0 Guide" and want to get Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

When I open https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/ I've got an error:

```
An internal error occurred (eid 7320968).
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iing8.png)

How I can resolve this?

Comment: I see it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Service has been restored**

I have the same issue, looks like an issue on Yahoo's end, have created a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024932/unable-to-create-new-yahoo-application) It seems a bit lame that Yahoo's developer support forum is a redirect to Stack Overflow, when most other major published APIs host and moderate their own forums.