# Unable to Create New Yahoo Application

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

This link has been finicky in the past, it appears to be completely dead now:
https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/

Is it not possible to create Yahoo applications anymore?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be directed at Yahoo.

Comment: Yahoo uses stackoverflow for troubleshooting: 

https://developer.yahoo.com/support/oauth/

I'm contacting them through whatever mediums they want me to use, seems like their service is dead.

I'd appreciate it if you wouldn't downvote this issue, I believe Yahoo uses Stack Overflow as a platform to address their dev community - I agree they should be hosting their own support forum.

Comment: If this was a coding problem it'd be a Stack Overflow question. The problem here is it's a question about the status of the *product*, which is something altogether different.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to determine - in any case the service has been restored, code is executing again.